# How to find the name of the package manager?

Tags: package-management

What command can I use to find the name of the package manager used by my OS?

Comment: What do you mean? It is not clear to me. There are many package managers available, all based on dpkg/apt at the core, it depends on your choice.

Comment: Is this a general question that spans multiple operating systems including OSes that are not Ubuntu-based? Or are you asking how to find out what package management utilities are available on your [particular "flavor"](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives) of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember, there is no way to determine what package manager is used by the system through a command. Usually, the package manager used are system specific and there is no way to use an alternative of that unless they are a front-end or back-end of the package manager.

For example, Ubuntu uses dpkg. Software-center is a graphical front-end of Advanced Packaging Tool (APT), which in turn is a command line front-end of dpkg.

You can take a look at the available [features of various package managers](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=package-management) at DistroWatch.

Also, to know what package managers are used by various operating system, you can check out the [list of software package management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems) on Wikipedia.